# Bloquear transacción y realizarla cuando un administrador lo confirme en Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, transacciones, symfony

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Symfony 3 y necesito estas se bloqueen todas las transacciones en la base de datos antes de realizarlas (insert, update y delete) y que se realicen cuando un admin lo confirme.

Tengo un formulario, y cuando hago alguna transacción (por ejemplo modificar algo), se modifica. Lo que necesito es que no se actualice, sino que se quede bloqueado hasta que un administrador confirme la transacción.

Tenéis alguna idea de como puedo hacer esto? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Imaginando que lo que buscas es un método de moderación de lo que hacen los usuarios en tu aplicación, el único método que veo que puedes implantar es crear una tabla en la base de datos con las query SQL que los usuarios han realizado (Inserts, updates y deletes) y, en el perfil de usuario administrador crear una ventana de moderación mostrando estos cambios para poder moderar.

En el caso que aceptes los cambios de una solicitud, sólo deberías ejecutar las SQL de esa moderación que has aceptado.

Tal y como se puede leer en la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) no hay manera de dejar una transacción pendiente a aceptación, siempre que se cierra una transacción se hace un Rollback si no se ha hecho el Commit.

Comment: El caso es que cuando hago click a enviar en el formulario, doctrine me hace la transacción directamente, y yo quiero que se bloquee o que no la haga

Answer (score 0):

Hay un problema básico acá:

Cuando se realiza una transacción SQL el único que puede ver los resultados TEMPORALES que pueda tener la transacción es el que la está realizando. 
Dicho de otra forma si hacés

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE products set price = 10 where id = 1;

select price from productos where id = 1;
```

price es igual a 10 solo para la conexión que está activa que es la que ESTÁ HACIENDO LA TRANSACCIÓN. No será visible price = 10 para el resto del mundo hasta que hagas el `COMMIT TRANSACTION;`.
Justamente por las propiedades [ACID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) nadie más tiene acceso a lo que está transacción está haciendo.

En tu caso lo que se suele hacer es guardar las modificaciones y marcarlas como pendientes de aprobar en alguna tabla  (products_modified se me ocurre) y guardar aquí los datos a aprobar quizá con el identificador del usuario que realiza la modificación, fecha, hora etc.